# How do you slice a pandas dataframe as an argument in a function?

Tags: python, pandas, getattr

What I am looking to do is to put the rules of slicing a pandas dataframe in a function.

For example:

```
row1 = {'a':5,'b':6,'c':7,'d':'A'}
row2 = {'a':8,'b':9,'c':10,'d':'B'}
row3 = {'a':11,'b':12,'c':13,'d':'C'}
df = pd.DataFrame([row1,row2,row3])
```

I am slicing the dataframe this way:

```
print df.loc[df['a']==5]
print df.loc[df['b']==12]
print df.loc[(df['b']==12) | df['d'].isin(['A','C']),'d']
```

For my purposes, I need to slice the same dataframe in different ways as part of a function. For example:

```
def slicing(locationargument):
    df.loc(locationargument)
    do some stuff..
    return something
```

Alternatively, I was expecting getattr() to work but that tells me DataFrames do not have a .loc[...] attribute. For example:

```
getattr(df,"loc[df['a']==5]")
```

Returns:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'loc[df['a']==5]'
```

Am I missing something here? Any thoughts or alternatives would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Call like `slicing(df['a']==5)` and do `df.loc[locationargument]` inside of the function. Is that what you want?

Comment: Exactly - or of course, some alternative that fulfills similar functionality..

Comment: Would it not be easier and make more sense to turn whatever `do something...` into a function that you perform on the slice? So you slice outside the function and pass the slice to the function?

Comment: I was considering this as well, but I need to slice several dataframes in the same way, so I would need to do it multiple times. I was looking to have the function take the locationargument and apply it to all dataframes in one call. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Pandas, I believe it's not quite right to think of `.loc` as a function (or method) on a `DataFrame`.  For example, the syntax `df.loc(...)` is not right.  Instead, you need to write `df.loc[...]` (brackets, not parentheses).

So how about simply:

```
def slicing(locationargument):
    df.loc[locationargument]
    do some stuff..
    return something
```

But then the question becomes "what type of object should `locationargument` be?  If it's an iterable whose length is equal to the number of rows in your data frame, you're all set.  An alternative could be to make it a string and then write:

```
def slicing(locationargumentstring):
    df.loc[eval(locationargumentstring)]
    do some stuff..
    return something
```

If you go the `getattr` route, remember that the attribute doesn't include parameters.  So the following is bad:

```
getattr(df, "loc[df['a']==5]")
```

but the following would work:

```
getattr(df, "loc")[eval("df['a']==5")]
```

and, more directly, so would

```
getattr(df, "loc")[df['a']==5]
```

Comment: This definitely did work. It did make sense that .loc was not considered a method of DataFrame. I was so close. Now that I am seeing this, it seems there's more about the getattr() function than I know now. Time for some digging.. Thanks!

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert, but think of `x = getattr(foo, bar)` as equivalent to `x = foo.bar`.  In particular, `bar` should be a string or something that evaluates to a string.  And in that case `x` winds up being whatever kind of thing the `bar` attribute on `foo` was to begin with.  So if `foo.bar` is a function, you can do `getattr(foo, bar)(arguments)` and if `foo.bar` is a float you can do `getattr(foo, bar) * 2`, etc.

Comment: And in the case of .loc in pandas (or any other indices for that matter, we can call [index] instead of (args) it seems? This is would think is generalizeable for any other Python object's attribute that takes a similar form..